# What is the difference between NetSuitePortType and NetSuiteService?

Tags: c#, wsdl, netsuite

The netsuite documentation indicates to use NetSuiteService; but I cannot find that object to instantiate.  I have NetSuitePortTypeClient instead.  Was a step missed when I imported the Service Reference?

I followed the instructions on page 23 of this documentation: http://www.netsuite.com/portal/partners/integration/download/SuiteTalkWebServicesPlatformGuide_2013.1.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The NetSuite/SuiteTalk documentation says to add a Web Reference, not a Service reference.

The Service Reference has the NetSuitePortTypeClient or NetSuiteChannelTypeClient classes.  I don't know all the differences between the Service Reference and Web Reference technologies, but you have to provide more parameters for those to classes, that are provided automatically for you with the NetSuite class of a Web Reference.  A Service Reference is generated with SVCUTIL.exe under the covers by VS for you.

The Web Reference has the NetSuite class you can instantiate.  This is generated with WSDL.exe under the covers by VS for you.  You can add a Web Reference in VS2010 down at the bottom left of the Add Service Reference form, click on Advanced, then click on Add Web Referenceat the bottom left again, and then enter the URL to where the WSDL is defined.  Don't forget that NetSuite has multiple different versions, from 2010 up to 2014, so pick the most recent that works for you.

Use the Web Reference for NetSuite, it's easier.

Bo.

Comment: Bo, thanks for the clarification!  I just tested this and it worked fine.

Comment: the great thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from. Thank you kindly for pointing out which standard to use in this case, there doesn't seem to be much clarification on this point elsewhere.